# c# Converting codepage input to display as Unicode

Tags: c#, unicode, encoding

I searched and find some partial answers that work in some instances but nothing that works in all. The scenarion is I get sent via network an XML file. The file has the encoding named  e.g. encoding = "Windows-932" or encoding = "Windows-1254" and so on. I need to parse the file and get certain info and the convert that info to Unicode chars and send it on to another machine that can only read Unicode.

So is the encoding is

- 1253 it is Cyrillic so Char E1 = ASCII225 = Unicode 0431.
- 1254 it is Turkish so Char E1 = ASCII225 = Unicode 00E1.
- 1251 it is Greek so Char E1 = ASCII225 = Unicode 03B1.

So far I thought I could have a loookup table that looked at the encoding and then I just add the Unicode page in front of the E1 BUT that will not work as in Unicode they do not have the same page position as you see above.

To further complicate things I can also get encoding such as Japanese (shift-JIS) which is codepage 932. Now this does not get all the japanese from the same page and almost every character on the ASCII pages comes from a different Unicode page.

So the question is how in C# do I convert the XML data to Unicode and get it correct everytime? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1253").GetString(new byte[] {0xE1})  // -> "\u03B1" α
Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1254").GetString(new byte[] {0xE1})  // -> "\u00E1" á
Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251").GetString(new byte[] {0xE1})  // -> "\u0431" б
```

But for an XML file you should be using an existing XML parser (eg `XmlReader` or `XDocument.Load`) which will deal with encodings for you.